# 'Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory()' returns a SessionFactory's object which is an interface not implemented by Configuration class?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, sessionfactory

How does the line `Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory()`   returns a `SessionFactory`'s object which is an interface not implemented by `Configuration` class?

Comment: Why do you think that this object should be implemented by `Configuration` class?

Comment: i just want to know how the method buildSessionFactory() builds/configures which class's 'object' that is returned & stored in SessionFactory's reference.

Comment: hey genius it would be more useful if u have hav answered atleast smthin else then decrementing!!!

Comment: the object is of type "SessionFactoryImpl" which implements SessionFactory interface!!!!!!!!!!!...bttr reply in answeres then in questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hibernate project is open source.  You're welcome to [look](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.java.html) for yourself.

```
public SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {
    log.debug( "Preparing to build session factory with filters : " + filterDefinitions );
    secondPassCompile();
    validate();
    Environment.verifyProperties( properties );
    Properties copy = new Properties();
    copy.putAll( properties );
    PropertiesHelper.resolvePlaceHolders( copy );
    Settings settings = buildSettings( copy );

    return new SessionFactoryImpl(
            this,
            mapping,
            settings,
            getInitializedEventListeners(),
            sessionFactoryObserver
        );
}
```